# Apple Music, difference between "Add to Library" and "Love"?

Tags: iphone, itunes, apple-music, music.app

I'm coming from Spotify to Apple Music.  Using Spotify, I can like a song with a single key press and it is added to my music library.  This song is used in Spotify's algorithms for my weekly Discover Playlist.  Using Apple Music requires some additional key presses to "Add to Library" and/or "Love" a song.  The key presses are through the track pane to "..." icon, then "Add to Library" and/or "Love", so a bit cumbersome if you're on the treadmill at a gym.

That aside, does anyone know the differences between "Add to Library" and/or "Love"?  Do I need to select both to get similar functionality as Spotify in my weekly Discover Playlist?

Comment: Have you tried creating a shortcut?

Comment: Won't the shortcut involve potentially more keypresses and/or Siri voice command?

Comment: So test both, but trying to command Siri when a track is playing...